# codeigniter query not working - response is null

Tags: sql, codeigniter, model

I have the following function in  my codeigniter Model:

```
  function get_as_09($q){
    $sql=("select length from
(SELECT  
      [length]
    ,CONCAT(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE([ProductCode],concat(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'')) as options

  FROM [database].[dbo].[ProductList]) as p
  where options='$q' order by length");
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['length'])); //build an array
       }
       return $row_set;
    }
  }
```

This is not working or returning a result.

the sql syntax below does indeed return a result:

```
select length from
(SELECT  
      [length]
      ,CONCAT(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE([ProductCode],concat(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'')) as options

  FROM [database].[dbo].[ProductList]) as p
  where options='25100cr' order by length
```

am I passing the $q variable to the query correctly? is my syntax in general correct?

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your `$sql`string? See what happens when you get rid of them

Comment: Thanks Mushark, if I take them away, I get an error.Network XHR response is error 42000 occurred, incorrect syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You have a rather serious sql injection problem with the `"...options='$q'..."` in the middle of your query too. Try rewriting it to `$this->db->query("... options=? ...", array($q));`

Comment: In which file is this function ?